# Log4J2 (2.17.1) - Delete logs automatically (Multiple filename conditions)

Tags: properties, log4j2

I'm currently trying to get the Delete Action running in one of my log4j2.properties files.
There is the possibility to delete log files, with preconfigured conditions, like file size or age. The information about that is really rare on the web, but enough to configure it someway. Anyway, it's not working for me.

We are using a properties file to configure our Log4J2. The writing works absolutely as expected, the deletion works too. But as soon as I specify multiple filenames for the deletion, the deletion happens only on the last entry of it.
Do you know of another way to accomplish this?

Here's a snippet of our properties file, which deletes only the log4j.logs:

```
appender.aokwf.strategy.action.type = Delete
appender.aokwf.strategy.action.basepath = D:/logs/
appender.aokwf.strategy.action.maxdepth = 1
appender.aokwf.strategy.action.condition.type = IfLastModified
appender.aokwf.strategy.action.condition.age = 1D
appender.aokwf.strategy.action.PathConditions.type = IfFileName
appender.aokwf.strategy.action.PathConditions.glob = workflow_logging*.log.zip
appender.aokwf.strategy.action.PathConditions.type = IfFileName
appender.aokwf.strategy.action.PathConditions.glob = log4j.log.*
```

When specifying multiple Filenames for deletion in log4j2.properties i expect it to delete both conditions.
In fact it only deletes the last entry

Answer (score 0):

To make a logical disjunction of the two conditions, you can use [`IfAny`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/javadoc/log4j-core/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/action/IfAny.html):

```xml
<IfAny>
  <IfFileName glob="workflow_logging*.log.zip"/>
  <IfFileName glob="log4j.log.*"/>
</IfAny>
```

Encoding this in a property file will give you something like:

```
appender.aokwf.strategy.action.0.type = IfAny
appender.aokwf.strategy.action.0.0.type = IfFileName
appender.aokwf.strategy.action.0.0.glob = workflow_logging*.log.zip
appender.aokwf.strategy.action.0.1.type = IfFileName
appender.aokwf.strategy.action.0.1.glob = log4j.log.*
```